# WCF - Getting the "The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') ....." error

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-express

"The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Ntlm'). "

I am brand new to WCF and services in general.  I have turned on the basic, windows & digest auth modes in my iis express.

One thing I just noticed in my iis express config file, I had turned on basic auth in the "turn of windows stuff" in the task manager then rebooted, but I just opened the applicationhost.config file on my machine and saw this:

```
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
```

shouldn't that basicAuthentication read as true?

I was given this existing project to make some changes to, but I cant even get it to run on my machine, so I'm assuming something is up with my local iis express settings.

This project has 3 services in it.  Here is a partial of the webConfig:

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataMaintenanceService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IYearEndProcessingService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even though I had enabled the various auth types in the "Turn on windows features...", they didn't actually turn on, so I had to modify the iis config file manually.  I found the config file in the iisExpress folder in My Documents.